# Iterate over all but d-th dimension of any boost::multi_array

Tags: c++, arrays, boost, iterator, boost-multi-array

Quite often one wants to apply operation `f()` along dimension `d` of an `N`-dimensional array `A`. This implies looping over all remaining dimensions of `A`. I tried to figure out if `boost::multi_array` was capable of this. Function `f(A)` should work on all varieties of `boost::multi_array`, including `boost:multi_array_ref`,  `boost::detail::multi_array::sub_array`, and `boost::detail::multi_array::array_view`, ideally also for the rvalue types such as `boost::multi_array_ref<T, NDims>::reference`.

The best I could come up with is an implementation of a `reshape()` function that can be used to reshape the ND array into a 3D array, such that the working dimension is always the middle one. Here is `f.hpp`:

```
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp"
#include <ostream>

using namespace boost;

typedef multi_array_types::index index_t;
typedef multi_array_types::index_range range;

template <template <typename, std::size_t, typename...> class Array,
          typename T, std::size_t NDims, typename index_t, std::size_t NDimsNew>
multi_array_ref<T, NDimsNew>
reshape(Array<T, NDims>& A, const array<index_t, NDimsNew>& dims) {
    multi_array_ref<T, NDimsNew> a(A.origin(), dims);
    return a;
}

template <template <typename, std::size_t, typename...> class Array, typename T>
void f(Array<T, 1>& A) {
    for (auto it : A) {
        // do something with it
        std::cout << it << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template <template <typename, std::size_t, typename...> class Array, 
          typename T, std::size_t NDims>
void f(Array<T, NDims>& A, long d) {
    auto dims = A.shape();
    typedef typename std::decay<decltype(*dims)>::type type;

    // collapse dimensions [0,d) and (d,Ndims)
    array<type, 3> dims3 = {
        std::accumulate(dims, dims + d, type(1), std::multiplies<type>()),
        dims[d],
        std::accumulate(dims + d + 1, dims + NDims, type(1), std::multiplies<type>())
    };

    // reshape to collapsed dimensions
    auto A3 = reshape(A, dims3);

    // call f for each slice [i,:,k]
    for (auto Ai : A3) {
        for (index_t k = 0; k < dims3[2]; ++k) {
            auto S = Ai[indices[range()][k]];
            f(S);
        }
    }
}

template <template <typename, std::size_t, typename...> class Array, 
          typename T, std::size_t NDims>
void f(Array<T, NDims>& A) {
    for (long d = NDims; d--; ) {
        f(A, d);
    }
}
```

This is the test program `test.cpp`:

```
#include "f.hpp"

int main() {
    boost::multi_array<double, 3> A(boost::extents[2][2][3]);
    boost::multi_array_ref<double, 1> a(A.data(), boost::extents[A.num_elements()]);
    auto Ajk = A[1];
    auto Aik = A[boost::indices[range()][1][range()]];

    int i = 0;
    for (auto& ai : a) ai = i++;

    std::cout << "work on boost::multi_array_ref" << std::endl;
    f(a);

    std::cout << "work on boost::multi_array" << std::endl;
    f(A);

    std::cout << "work on boost::detail::multi_array:sub_array" << std::endl;
    f(Ajk);

    std::cout << "work on boost::detail::multi_array:sub_array" << std::endl;
    f(Aik);   // wrong result, since reshape() ignores strides!

    //f(A[1]);   // fails: rvalue A[1] is boost::multi_array_ref<double, 3ul>::reference
}
```

Clearly, there are problems with this approach, namely when a slice is passed to `f()`, such that the memory is no longer contiguous, which defeats the implementation of `reshape()`.

It appears a better (more C++-like) way would be to construct an aggregate iterator out of the iterators that the boost types provide, since this would automatically take care of non-unity strides along a given dimension. `boost::detail::multi_array::index_gen` looks relevant, but it is not quite clear to me how this can be used to make an iterator over all slices in dimension `d`. Any ideas?

*Note:*

There are similar questions already on SO, but none was quite satisfactory to me. I am not interested in specialized solutions for `N = 3` or `N = 2`. It's got to work for any `N`.

*Update:*

Here is the equivalent of what I want in Python:

```
def idx_iterator(s, d, idx):
    if len(s) == 0:
        yield idx
    else: 
        ii = (slice(None),) if d == 0 else xrange(s[0])
        for i in ii:
            for new_idx in idx_iterator(s[1:], d - 1, idx + [i]):
                yield new_idx

def iterator(A, d=0):
    for idx in idx_iterator(A.shape, d, []):
        yield A[idx]

def f(A):
    for d in reversed(xrange(A.ndim)):
        for it in iterator(A, d):
            print it
        print

import numpy as np
A = np.arange(12).reshape((2, 2, 3))

print "Work on flattened array"
f(A.ravel())

print "Work on array"
f(A)

print "Work on contiguous slice"
f(A[1])

print "Work on discontiguous slice"
f(A[:,1,:])
```

The same should somehow be possible using the functionality in `index_gen.hpp`, but I have still not been able to figure out how.

Comment: did you see the explanation under [MultiArray Concept](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/multi_array/doc/reference.html#MultiArray)? Esp. the _" For example, if indices is an object of type index_gen, then the following example:

`indices[index_range(0,5)][2][index_range(0,4)]`;
has a degenerate second dimension. The view generated from the above specification will have 2 dimensions with shape 5 x 4"_

Comment: I noticed. Note how I removed that comment 5 minutes ago :)

Comment: @sehe: Yes, I read this. Suppose I get such a `5 x 4` view object. Then I need to iterate first over the `5` dimension, applying `f()` along all slices of the `4` dimension, and vice versa. My approach fails in this case, since memory is not contiguous. That's why I think I must somehow make use of the iterators that the view object provides.

Comment: You can iterate the view, using the iterators. If it's important that the memory is actually contiguous, you're going to have to copy the data anyways

Comment: @sehe: It gets complicated to use these iterators for ND arrays, if the working dimension is `d`. If memory is contiguous, my approach already works. I want it to work also if any/some/all of the dimensions are not contiguous.

Comment: You're stating the obvious. You want more complex things, **ergo** you cannot use the simple approach. Would you rather write the complex iterations, or use the library, that has it implemented?

Comment: It is not clear to me how I can use "the library". I suspect `index_gen` is relevant, but I haven't figured out how to use it to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, after spending a significant amount of time studying the implementation of `boost::multi_array`, I am now ready to answer my own question: No, there are no provisions anywhere in `boost::multi_array` that would allow one to iterate along any but the first dimension. The best I could come up with is to construct an iterator that manually manages the `N-1` indices that are being iterated over. Here is `slice_iterator.hpp`:

```
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp"

template <template <typename, std::size_t, typename...> class Array,
          typename T, std::size_t NDims>
struct SliceIterator {
    typedef Array<T, NDims> array_type;
    typedef typename array_type::size_type size_type;
    typedef boost::multi_array_types::index_range range;
    typedef boost::detail::multi_array::multi_array_view<T, 1> slice_type;
    typedef boost::detail::multi_array::index_gen<NDims, 1> index_gen;

    array_type& A;
    const size_type* shape;
    const long d;
    index_gen indices;
    bool is_end = false;

    SliceIterator(array_type& A, long d) : A(A), shape(A.shape()), d(d) {
        int i = 0;
        for (; i != d; ++i) indices.ranges_[i] = range(0);
        indices.ranges_[i++] = range();
        for (; i != NDims; ++i) indices.ranges_[i] = range(0);
    }

    SliceIterator& operator++() {
        // addition with carry, excluding dimension d
        int i = NDims - 1;
        while (1) {
            if (i == d) --i;
            if (i < 0) {
                is_end = true;
                return *this;
            }
            ++indices.ranges_[i].start_;
            ++indices.ranges_[i].finish_;
            if (indices.ranges_[i].start_ < shape[i]) {
                break;
            } else {
                indices.ranges_[i].start_ = 0;
                indices.ranges_[i].finish_ = 1;
                --i;
            }
        }
        return *this; 
    }

    slice_type operator*() { 
        return A[indices];
    }

    // fakes for iterator protocol (actual implementations would be expensive)
    bool operator!=(const SliceIterator& r) {
        return !is_end;
    }

    SliceIterator begin() {return *this;}
    SliceIterator end()   {return *this;}
};

template <template <typename, std::size_t, typename...> class Array,
          typename T, std::size_t NDims>
SliceIterator<Array, T, NDims> make_slice_iterator(Array<T, NDims>& A, long d) {
    return SliceIterator<Array, T, NDims>(A, d);
}

// overload for rvalue references
template <template <typename, std::size_t, typename...> class Array,
          typename T, std::size_t NDims>
SliceIterator<Array, T, NDims> make_slice_iterator(Array<T, NDims>&& A, long d) {
    return SliceIterator<Array, T, NDims>(A, d);
}
```

It can be used as

```
for (auto S : make_slice_iterator(A, d)) {
    f(S);
}
```

and works for all examples in my question.

I must say that `boost::multi_array`'s implementation was quite disappointing to me: Over 3700 lines of code for what should be little more than a bit of index housekeeping. In particular the iterators, which are only provided for the first dimension, aren't anywhere near a performance implementation: There are actually up to `3*N + 5` comparisons carried out at each step to decide whether the iterator has arrived at the end yet (note that my implementation above avoids this problem by faking `operator!=()`), which makes this implementation unsuitable for anything but arrays with a dominant last dimension, which is handled more efficiently. Moreover, the implementation doesn't take advantage of dimensions that are contiguous in memory. Instead, it always proceeds dimension-by-dimension for operations such as array assignment, wasting significant optimization opportunities.

In summary, I find `numpy`'s implementation of an N-dimensional array much more compelling than this one. There are 3 more observations that tell me "Hands Off" of `boost::multi_array`:

- I couldn't find any serious use cases for `boost::multi_array` anywhere on the web
- Development appears to have essentially stopped in 2002
- This (and similar) questions on StackOverflow have hardly generated any interest ;-)

Comment: I feel the pain. You can use this alternative library that supports partial index access https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi/-/blob/master/README.md#element-access-and-partial-access and has a .elements() methods that flattens the elements regardless of the layout in memory, so `A(_, 1, _).elements()` gives you a range of elements for a second fixed index. Here it is a working example: https://godbolt.org/z/xTx6brYsT